# Facebook share post - limit URL to title and image only

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

While sharing post to my wall, I am getting link on complete post whereas I want to show the URL to shared post title and image only. Everything working fine except the link part.

```
$result = $facebook->api('/me/feed/', 'post',
    array('name' => $_POST['title'], 
          'link' => 'http://myurl.com', 
          'picture' => $_POST['imgPath'], 
          'caption' => 'post title', 
          'description' => $_POST['description']));
```

Please suggest.

Comment: I can’t understand what exactly it is you’re asking for.

Comment: @CBroe Actually, If you see any shared post on your wall than you will find that the link is on the title and thumbnail only but in my case it get linked to complete post.

Comment: @CBroe [link]http://www.facebook.com/HyperArtsTests?sk=app_198144043559967  check the dialogue box appear on click of share

Comment: I still have no idea what you might want to know.

Comment: @CBroe it is solved now by changing

    $result = $facebook->api('/me/feed/', 'post',

to 

    $result = $facebook->api('/feed/', 'post',

Answer (score 0):

```
Try by removing '/' after feed ..
$result = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'post',
    array('name' => $_POST['title'], 
          'link' => 'http://myurl.com', 
          'picture' => $_POST['imgPath'], 
          'caption' => 'post title', 
          'description' => $_POST['description']));    
or you can use userid instead of me..
$user=$facebook->getUser();
$result = $facebook->api('/$user/feed', 'post',
    array('name' => $_POST['title'], 
          'link' => 'http://myurl.com', 
          'picture' => $_POST['imgPath'], 
          'caption' => 'post title', 
          'description' => $_POST['description']));
```